# copy methods from one class to another (python)

Tags: python, class, monkeypatching

so i don't know if what i am asking for is even passable or not, but never the less, i want to do is the following

```
class A:
    def methodA(self):
        pass
    def methodB(self):
        pass

class B:
    pass


b = B()

b.methodA()
b.methodB()
```

but the thing is i might going to have so many number of class B objects this is why i want to assign the "A"s methods to the B class rather than to a single object of class B, i found one solution but the problem with it i have to pass the object as a parameter so for example i am going to have something like this

```
b.methodA(b)
b.methodB(b)
```

**edited**
so the reason why i want to do such thing is, i am making a program that will have two python interpreter whose interpreting the same python file, and i want to share objects between them by only sending/receiving the data inside the object along with the object type, so that the other interpreter will only receive the object data along with its type and make new object from class like the B class, and since both of the interpreters  are interpreting the same python file, both of them will have access to the object class, so i don't really have to send the object methods, i can simply make the other interpreter copy it(if it was passable)

**edited**
so i will need to assign the methods and removing them in run time, and i won't be able to know what classes are the class B are going to copy methods from, until the code execution finishes

Comment: Why doesn't `B` *inherit* those methods from `A`?

Comment: for my application it must happen dynamically, the B class will add and delete new methods:)

Comment: @void It appears from your latest edits that you may be asking about object serialisation. If you have control over the definition of the classes, you might be able to solve your problem by [making them pickleable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances).

Comment: They actually pickle-able but the problem with pickel it's very slow, and I think I might be able to optimized the serilazation process a lot for my program

Comment: @void Sounds like premature optimisation. If you don't do real-world testing, claiming that "x is very slow" is meaningless, since all the other serialisation methods might be even slower.

Comment: @void You still haven't really explained why you need to copy/remove methods of `B` at runtime. If you can import class `A` into both programs and instantiate it from data sent between the programs, I don't see why you can't simply call the instance methods directly (perhaps via `__getattr__` through a wrapper interface).

Answer (score 0):

You can check Class inheritance or Polymorphism. If you have only one class that should use other's function, Inheritance is better. One will be the child of other. For example, if `B` will be the child of `A`, `B` will have `A` functions and more. read more at:
Example:

Parent

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    self.firstname = fname
    self.lastname = lname

  def printname(self):
    print(self.firstname, self.lastname)

#Use the Person class to create an object, and then execute the printname method:

x = Person("John", "Doe")
x.printname()
```

Child class:

```
class Student(Person):
  pass
```

Then you could use Person's functions from Student:

```
x = Student("Mike", "Olsen")
x.printname()
```

read more: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

Comment: i just edit my question, thanks for your response but i don't think this will solve my problem

Answer (score -1):

You can pass class A into class B, if what you are doing is to let B have functions in A.

```
class A():
    def method1():
        return 'method1'
    def method2():
        return 'method2'
class B(A):
    pass

B.method1()
B.method2()
```

Comment: More specifically, you can add it as a `super`. You can define methods `methodA` and `methodB`, and add `super.methodA` and `super.methodB` in these new methods you are defining in class A

Comment: i just edit my question, thanks but i don't think this will solve my problem